# Animate a sequence of images (plot) inside a pdf?

Tags: animate

I have 6 images. I want to animate them inside my pdf. What this means is I want them to loop to show how as N increases we get more accurate estimate. 3 images are included here so you know what I mean.

Is it possible to have this animation in my pdf? I don't want to use documentclass{beamer} I want to use {article} for my purposes.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a package `animate` specifically for this.  Read the documentation - it has quite a few examples.

One of the problems with this package that so far the only viewer that can show animation is Adobe Acrobat, which is free as beer but not free as speech.  However, there is some work to create animate-aware free viewer.